# How to access a MS SQL Server public key in Java

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

We are trying to encrypt a file using a RSA 2048 public key created directly in the MS SQL Server. These public keys can supposedly be queried with sys.asymmetric_keys view. We don't really have access to the database. The public keys are stored as VARBINARY(max) field. And look something like this:

```
0x0602000000240000525341310008000001000100D1D13925EC404DA171AE1EA9EFCFCB9849FA
4678DB26D0EEDD36D440D5EC3781A7EE3E05654EC6830B79E5E745F24A0C35B21C0089D19254A7
A12B65EA018116482190B2D4DDADB2CD7B0B79F0E08DF97C4E4569D181BC3C34D350AEF821CCA0
819E4AA336449A4B022F75FC6C382C4BA60CBBBA03461D2B6C7BF7CECE48D52A6B186C57226297
A09DD5D730ECA29C41796C1C961AA7763D8F7D0094F310D29AEA8D5F526B0B99FEC1841B5462A0
75648CADBB32C51A43EAC76E8D02B644996368890A762AEF80439B4CD92DA7D38417601918B104
B1DDEE846DF09E944B562A0828285A6EB362D19E2BDD79DBCE6B86D9F60D264C8EF4F4CCCAEB6B
89F410AF
```

THe length of this public key is 554 digits. It seems like it is a hexadecimal number. I have no clue how this key is encoded. I do know that we need a KeySpec to instantiate a Public Key.

```
PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic((KeySpec) new SomeKeySpec(bytes);
```

I have no clue how create a Key Specification out of this.

Comment: Can you post a whole public key example? That would help us figure out the format.

Answer (score 1):

First let's take a look at the header before the public exponent:

```
06020000 00240000 2534131 00080000
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure about the first two values. `52534131` is ASCII for "RSA1", probably a label of some kind, and `00080000` is undoubtedly the key size, 0x0800 in 32 bit little endian, i.e. 2048.

`010001` is the public exponent. It is a well known one, the fourth number of Fermat (a prime number with the first and last bit set to `1`, all zero's in between). This makes it a fast public key.

This makes:

```
00 D1D13925EC404DA171AE1EA9EFCFCB98
   49FA4678DB26D0EEDD36D440D5EC3781
   A7EE3E05654EC6830B79E5E745F24A0C
   35B21C0089D19254A7A12B65EA018116

   482190B2D4DDADB2CD7B0B79F0E08DF9
   7C4E4569D181BC3C34D350AEF821CCA0
   819E4AA336449A4B022F75FC6C382C4B
   A60CBBBA03461D2B6C7BF7CECE48D52A

   6B186C57226297A09DD5D730ECA29C41
   796C1C961AA7763D8F7D0094F310D29A
   EA8D5F526B0B99FEC1841B5462A07564
   8CADBB32C51A43EAC76E8D02B6449963

   68890A762AEF80439B4CD92DA7D38417
   601918B104B1DDEE846DF09E944B562A
   0828285A6EB362D19E2BDD79DBCE6B86
   D9F60D264C8EF4F4CCCAEB6B89F410AF
```

the modulus, encoded as a big endian *signed* integer (hence the `00` in front of it.

Comment: Note that it could also be an unsigned values, where each value is separated by bytes valued `00`. There seem to be too many `00` valued bytes in the hexadecimal encoding.

Comment: Is this not enough of an answer for you, CodingWithLegos?